# PHP curl issue - error if using a variable as the URL, but a string works fine

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a very strange curl issue within php. When I pass in a URL as a variable, the request will return a 400 error saying "Bad Request - missing offer id cookie".

But if hard-code the URL into the code instead of passing a variable, it works fine!

Here is my code -

```
            function resolveURL($url) {

                $ch = curl_init("$url");  
                echo var_dump("$url");

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                $results = curl_exec($ch); 
                curl_close($ch); 

                echo var_dump($results);
            }
```

The var_dump of $url return - `string(104) "http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=SN4dmHdm/i8&offerid=462146.45&type=3&subid=0"`

The var_dump of $results returns

`string(319) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Length: 187 Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 14:14:38 GMT Connection: close Missing offer id cookie "`

But if I make one change to the code above -

`$ch = curl_init("http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=SN4dmHdm/i8&offerid=462146.45&type=3&subid=0");`

Then the $results returns the full data I expect-

`string(1125) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Set-Cookie: lsn_statp=SSUMBwoAAAAlJc5KdQpJiw%3D%3D; Domain=.linksynergy.com; Expires=Wed, 17-Dec-2036 14:16:14 GMT; Path=/ Set-Cookie: rmuid=e431e402-a482-4611-a78a-71aa74f859f5; Domain=.linksynergy.com; Expires=Fri, 22-Dec-2017 14:16:14 GMT; Path=/ Set-Cookie: lsn_qstring=SN4dmHdm%2Fi8%3A462146%3A; Domain=.linksynergy.com; Expires=Fri, 23-Dec-2016 14:16:14 GMT; Path=/ Set-Cookie: lsn_track=UmFuZG9tSVZDI%2Bw8hSY%2BdfkMlwCUwBvtWwSdxm0SOqHNgxhyQqiQeQ0nwzwxomWBIzUbWVW%2Ft7lFTQ3k3hZXdQ%3D%3D; Domain=.linksynergy.com; Expires=Sun, 20-Dec-2026 14:16:14 GMT; Path=/ Set-Cookie: lsclick_mid38366="2016-12-22 14:16:14.418|SN4dmHdm_i8-R8CHpEfhXw637RnHirbegw"; Version=1; Domain=.linksynergy.com; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Sat, 22-Dec-2018 14:16:14 GMT; Path=/ P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR BUS STA" Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 14:16:14 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Location: http://www.daskeyboard.com/?siteID=SN4dmHdm_i8-R8CHpEfhXw637RnHirbegw Content-Length: 0 Connection: close "`

Why is this the case? I figure for some reason, everything after the first `&` is getting stripped when I leave the URL as a variable, but I can't explain why.

I have tried running the $url through `urlencode()`, `htmlentities()`, and `htmlspecialchars()` but I still get the same results. I have tried passing in `$url` instead of `"$url"`, and nothing fixes the issue.

UPDATE: When I do a `echo var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` after setting the URL, it looks like the length of the string is somehow longer than it should be when passing in `$url`, but is the correct length when using the hard-coded string. Here are the results -

```
//$url
`array(21) { ["url"]=> string(104) "http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=SN4dmHdm/i8&offerid=462146.45&type=3&subid=0" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } } `

//hard-coded
`array(21) { ["url"]=> string(89) "http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=SN4dmHdm/i8&offerid=462146.45&type=3&subid=0" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } } `
```

Can anyone explain where the extra 15 characters are coming from when I use the variable?

**Update:** By doing a `str_split` on `$url`, I have found that for some reason, there is a hidden '#038;' in the variable after every `&` that does not show when I echo the string. Below is what the array returns -

```
[56]=> string(1) "&" [57]=> string(1) "#" [58]=> string(1) "0" [59]=> string(1) "3" [60]=> string(1) "8" [61]=> string(1) ";"
```

And here is what has fixed it..

```
$url= str_replace("#038;", "", $url);
```

Comment: The actual length of `http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=SN4dmHdm/i8&offerid=462146.45&type=3&subid=0` is 89. But in your case, you get `string (104)`, i.e the length is 104. Make sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that by doing a `echo var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` after setting the URL... I will update my post with the results, I don't understand what would be causing this.

Comment: How do you pass URL in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try assembling it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => $url,
   (the rest of your setopt array)
));
```

[More info](http://codular.com/curl-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different encoding for different parts of the request string.

Use rawurlencode() for URL, and then construct the request string using urlencode() for each parameter:

```
$url = rawurlencode("http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click");

$params_urlencoded = array_map("urlencode", $params);
$getfields = "id=".$params_urlencoded['id']
            ."&offerid=".$params_urlencoded['offerid']
            ."&type=".$params_urlencoded['type']
            ."&subid=".$params_urlencoded['subid'];

$ch = curl_init($url.'?'.$getfields);
```

It seems like your ampersands which delimit the parameter names get encoded as special characters (`&amp;`) thus more symbols and wrong variable names when parsed on server.

Also, read the docs :)

[B.2.2 Ampersands in URI attribute values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2)

[php urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

[php rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: The url that I pass into the function will be different all the time, so I won't know the base URL or parameters ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The moral of the story - I assume because I was debugging within a browser, I was unable to see that the ampersands in the URL were encoded with `"#038;"` even though I was echoing from php.

Apparently, curl will not work with these in place so the resolution was to strip them from the URL variable -

```
$url = str_replace("#038;", "", $url);
```

Afterwords the URL can be encoded as needed.